# fstream doesn't work in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, fstream

I have some code working when I compile it with Code Blocks,
so now that I want to use it in Qt5, I copied it. And it is doing nothing. i can run the application, but I can not read data out of my `.txt` file.
I included fstream, string, iostream and QCoreApplication.

```
fstream data;
data.open("Datenbank.txt",ios::in);

//Variables for Database
string DbName,ServerName,UserName,Password,Rolename,Charset,Parameters;
string NewForeName ="Alex";
// reading txt Data
data>>DbName;
data>>ServerName;
data>>UserName;
data>>Password;
data>>Rolename;
data>>Charset;
data>>Parameters;
cout<<"test"<<endl;

data.close();
cout<<DbName<<endl;
cout<<ServerName<<endl;
cout<<UserName<<endl;
cout<<Password<<endl;
cout<<"test2"<<endl;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried debugging? Also you don't seem to be checking if the file has been successfully opened. I'm quite sure you just don't have the file in the right place and it simply fails to open the file due to that. Add a fail check for the data.open() function, use is_open() or fail()/good() and report back.

Comment: Where is project and Datenbank.txt? If you use Qt Creator than you should know that Qt Creator creates separate directory build-..... for binary files. Maybe you just specify wrong path

Comment: You're using relative path, probably output dir for your project does not contain Datebank.txt file

Comment: ok i tried it. its a problem with opening the file. but my txt file is in the same  folder. how i fix it in qt. i just know fstream from code blocks. in that programm its enought to put it in the same folder

Comment: maybe post the folder layout for us? When you compile your project a folder with the project name and the build rules should appear, which has "Release" and "Debug" as subfolder. Copy the txt into that folder, NOT in the sub folders. EDIT: looks something like this "myproject-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug" but really depends on your project configuration

Comment: thank you Pannkuchen_gesicht thats the answer. didnt know that a new folder is created. u can mark your last comment as answer. its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile your project a folder with the project name and the build rules should appear, which has "Release" and "Debug" as sub folders. Copy the txt into that folder, NOT in the sub folders.
The folder name should look similiar to this:

```
myproject-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug
```